# More than 1 records with same id giving double data after join with another table

Tags: mysql, join

I am executing below query on two tables auditqueue_entry and rep_permission.
Table rep_permission having multiple records against **rep_id** which results in giving double payment amount after using aggregating function **sum**.

```
   Select aqe.rep_id, sum(aqe.payment) as aqauditcents
     From cclog.auditqueue_entry as aqe
Left Join ccconf.rep_permission 
       On aqe.rep_id = rep_permission.rep_id
    Where aqe.processedtime 
  Between "2015-11-09 00:00:00" 
      And "2015-11-10 00:00:00"
      And processedtime > 0
      And rep_permission.permission_id IN ($ids)
 Group By aqe.rep_id
```

For ex:-

rep_permission table:

```
+--------+---------------+
| rep_id | permission_id |
+--------+---------------+
|  60421 |            21 |
|  60421 |           451 |
+--------+---------------+
```

auditqueue_entry table:

```
+--------+---------+
| rep_id | payment |
+--------+---------+
|  60421 |     120 |
+--------+---------+
```

Current Output:

```
+--------+--------------+
| rep_id | aqauditcents |
+--------+--------------+
|  60421 |         240  | 
+--------+--------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+--------+--------------+
| rep_id | aqauditcents |
+--------+--------------+
|  60421 |         120  | 
+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the required rep_ids in subquery and then join it

```
select aqe.rep_id, sum(aqe.payment) as aqauditcents
from cclog.auditqueue_entry as aqe
left join (
    select distinct rep_id from rep_permission
    where rep_permission.permission_id IN ($ids)
) rep_permission on aqe.rep_id = rep_permission.rep_id
where aqe.processedtime between "2015-11-09 00:00:00" and "2015-11-10 00:00:00"
and processedtime > 0
group by aqe.rep_id
```